# Multiple SVN repos from same source folder

Tags: php, svn, repository

I am pretty new to SVN and after about 30 minutes of searching I can't find an answer to how to do this.  I have a bunch of files currently in one folder which belong in 2-3 different repositories.  I want to keep them the way they are (not move them into separate folders) but then when I am in that directory and tell it to commit, how will it know which repository I am talking about?  The reason I don't want to move the files is because it will break the path dependencies in the code on my dev environment (php on a server running apache) and I want to be able to have the dev environment continue working and only have one version of any given file floating around.  I am willing to use symbolic links if that would help.  Anyone know what is the right way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should read on [svn externals](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.advanced.externals).

Comment: don't externals give you a way to link in other directories from other repositories?  When I am in the main folder and say svn commit how will it know which ones to update?

Comment: It doesn't. for committing I go to a specific folder, but I can update in project root, and it updates everything.

Comment: So I would have to move the files into different folders so that the commit works correctly?  I don't want to have to move the files because it will break path dependencies in the code for includes and such. Maybe if I move the original file and replace the old position with a symbolic link...

Comment: ok I think I will try that.  Thanks for the help.  Even though externals aren't exactly what I needed in this case for the commit part, I will need them later.